# <style> attribute inside nodemailer ejs (email-templates) email template

Tags: css, node.js, email, templates, nodemailer

I am using node email-template to create email templates for sending emails. However I want to add **style** attribute inside template like below:

```
<style>
table{ //some style}
</style>
Hello,
  <table> </table>
Thanks,
```

How to add styles without giving inline css.

Comment: Check This link : http://blog.mailgun.com/transactional-html-email-templates/